# Spring Boot Social Login and Local OAuth2-Server

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot-Application with OAuth2-Authentication. I have a local OAuth2-Server where I receive a token when posting username and password of the local database against in my case http://localhost:8080/v1/oauth/token using Spring Boot's UserDetails and UserService. Everything works fine and nice.

But now I want to enhance my program with Facebook social login and want either log in to my local OAuth2-Server or using the external Facebook-Server. I checked out the Spring Boot example https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ and adapted the idea of an SSO-Filter. Now I can login using my Facebook client and secret id, but I cannot access my restricted localhost-sites.

What I want is that the Facebook-Token "behaves" the same way as the locally generated tokens by for instance being part of my local token storage. I checked out several tutorials and other Stackoverflow questions but with no luck. Here is what I have so far with a custom Authorization-Server and I think I'm still missing something very basic to get the link between external Facebook- and internal localhost-Server:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {
private static final String SERVER_RESOURCE_ID = "oauth2-server";

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

protected class ClientResources {
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Client
protected class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${pia.requireauth}")
    private boolean requireAuth;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (!requireAuth) {
            http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        } else {
            http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .exceptionHandling().and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                    .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${pia.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
    private int expiration;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    // password encryptor
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore).approvalStoreDisabled();
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("pia").secret("alphaport").accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
                .authorities("ROLE_USER").scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .resourceIds(SERVER_RESOURCE_ID);
    }
}
```

}

Any help and/or examples covering this issue greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Hello Christian, as I am facing the same problem, I am wondering if you have managed to find a solution to this. If you have please do write here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to implement the `Authentication Filter` and `Authentication Provider`.

In my case I've implemented an `OAuth2` authentication and also permit the user to access some endpoints with facebook `access_token`

The Authentication Filter looks like this:

```
public class ServerAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private BearerAuthenticationProvider bearerAuthenticationProvider;
    private FacebookAuthenticationProvider facebookAuthenticationProvider;

    public ServerAuthenticationFilter(BearerAuthenticationProvider bearerAuthenticationProvider,
            FacebookAuthenticationProvider facebookAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.bearerAuthenticationProvider = bearerAuthenticationProvider;
        this.facebookAuthenticationProvider = facebookAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        Optional<String> authorization = Optional.fromNullable(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization"));
        try {
            AuthType authType = getAuthType(authorization.get());
            if (authType == null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            String strToken = authorization.get().split(" ")[1];
            if (authType == AuthType.BEARER) {
                if (strToken != null) {
                    Optional<String> token = Optional.of(strToken);
                    logger.debug("Trying to authenticate user by Bearer method. Token: " + token.get());
                    processBearerAuthentication(token);
                }
            } else if (authType == AuthType.FACEBOOK) {
                if (strToken != null) {
                    Optional<String> token = Optional.of(strToken);
                    logger.debug("Trying to authenticate user by Facebook method. Token: " + token.get());
                    processFacebookAuthentication(token);
                }
            }
            logger.debug(getClass().getSimpleName() + " is passing request down the filter chain.");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException internalAuthenticationServiceException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            logger.error("Internal Authentication Service Exception", internalAuthenticationServiceException);
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            e.printStackTrace();
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private AuthType getAuthType(String value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        String[] basicSplit = value.split(" ");
        if (basicSplit.length != 2)
            return null;
        if (basicSplit[0].equalsIgnoreCase("bearer"))
            return AuthType.BEARER;
        if (basicSplit[0].equalsIgnoreCase("facebook"))
            return AuthType.FACEBOOK;
        return null;
    }

    private void processBearerAuthentication(Optional<String> token) {
        Authentication resultOfAuthentication = tryToAuthenticateWithBearer(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(resultOfAuthentication);
    }

    private void processFacebookAuthentication(Optional<String> token) {
        Authentication resultOfAuthentication = tryToAuthenticateWithFacebook(token);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(resultOfAuthentication);
    }

    private Authentication tryToAuthenticateWithBearer(Optional<String> token) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken requestAuthentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(token,
                null);
        return tryToAuthenticateBearer(requestAuthentication);
    }

    private Authentication tryToAuthenticateWithFacebook(Optional<String> token) {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken requestAuthentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(token,
                null);
        return tryToAuthenticateFacebook(requestAuthentication);
    }

    private Authentication tryToAuthenticateBearer(Authentication requestAuthentication) {
        Authentication responseAuthentication = bearerAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(requestAuthentication);
        if (responseAuthentication == null || !responseAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Unable to Authenticate for provided credentials.");
        }
        logger.debug("Application successfully authenticated by bearer method.");
        return responseAuthentication;
    }

    private Authentication tryToAuthenticateFacebook(Authentication requestAuthentication) {
        Authentication responseAuthentication = facebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(requestAuthentication);
        if (responseAuthentication == null || !responseAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(
                    "Unable to Authenticate for provided credentials.");
        }
        logger.debug("Application successfully authenticated by facebook method.");
        return responseAuthentication;
    }

}
```

This, filters Authorization headers, identifies whether they are facebook or bearer and then directs to specific provider.

The Facebook Provider looks like this:

```
public class FacebookAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Value("${config.oauth2.facebook.resourceURL}")
    private String facebookResourceURL;

    private static final String PARAMETERS = "fields=name,email,gender,picture";

    @Autowired
    FacebookUserRepository facebookUserRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        Optional<String> token = auth.getPrincipal() instanceof Optional ? (Optional) auth.getPrincipal() : null;
        if (token == null || !token.isPresent() || token.get().isEmpty())
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Grants");
        SocialResourceUtils socialResourceUtils = new SocialResourceUtils(facebookResourceURL, PARAMETERS);
        SocialUser socialUser = socialResourceUtils.getResourceByToken(token.get());
        if (socialUser != null && socialUser.getId() != null) {
            User user = findOriginal(socialUser.getId());
            if (user == null)
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed.");
            Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
            credentials.setId(user.getId());
            credentials.setUsername(user.getEmail());
            credentials.setName(user.getName());
            credentials.setRoles(parseRoles(user.translateRoles()));
            credentials.setToken(token.get());
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials, credentials.getId(),
                    parseAuthorities(getUserRoles(user.getId())));
        } else
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed.");

    }

    protected User findOriginal(String id) {
        FacebookUser facebookUser = facebookUserRepository.findByFacebookId(facebookId);
        return null == facebookUser ? null : userRepository.findById(facebookUser.getUserId()).get();
    }

    protected List<String> getUserRoles(String id) {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        userRoleRepository.findByUserId(id).forEach(applicationRole -> roles.add(applicationRole.getRole()));
        return roles;
    }

    private List<Roles> parseRoles(List<String> strRoles) {
        List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String strRole : strRoles) {
            roles.add(Roles.valueOf(strRole));
        }
        return roles;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> parseAuthorities(Collection<String> roles) {
        if (roles == null || roles.size() == 0)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        return roles.stream().map(role -> (GrantedAuthority) () -> "ROLE_" + role).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

The `FacebookUser` only makes a reference to the Local User Id and the Facebook Id (this is the link between facebook and our application).

This `SocialResourceUtils` is used to get the facebook user information via facebook API (using the method `getResourceByToken`). The facebook resource url is setted on `application.properties` (`config.oauth2.facebook.resourceURL`). This method is basically:

```
    public SocialUser getResourceByToken(String token) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String authorization = token;
        JsonNode response = null;
        try {
            response = restTemplate.getForObject(accessUrl + authorization, JsonNode.class);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed.");
        }
        return buildSocialUser(response);
    }
```

The `Bearer Provider` is your local Authentication, you can make your own, or use the springboot defaults, use other authentication methods, idk (I will not put my implementation here, thats by you).

And finally you need to make your Web Security Configurer:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("security.basic.enabled")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private BearerAuthenticationProvider bearerAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private FacebookAuthenticationProvider facebookAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(new ServerAuthenticationFilter(bearerAuthenticationProvider,
                facebookAuthenticationProvider), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

Notice that it has the annotation `ConditionalOnProperty` to enable/disable on properties `security.basic.enabled`. The `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` enables the usage of the annotation `@PreAuthorize` which enables us to protect endpoints by roles for example (using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole ('ADMIN')")` over an endpoint, to allow acces only to admins)

This code needs many improvements, but I hope I have helped.